# How to query a single document by custom parameter and update it in Firebase 9

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a custom ID in my Firebase documents. I want to get a single document querying by that custom ID and modify it. I'm using firebase v9.

Here's my code so far:

```
  const toggleLike = async () => {

    const q = query(collection(db, 'mixrCocktails'), where('id', '==', cocktailId))   
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q)
    const result: any[] = []
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => result.push(doc.data()) )

    if (!isLiked) {
      await updateDoc(result[0], { userLikes: arrayUnion(publisherId) })
      setIsLiked(true)
    }
    else {
      await updateDoc(result[0], { userLikes: arrayRemove(publisherId) })
      setIsLiked(false)
    }
  }
```

The query works fine, but the problem is when I run `updateDoc` . I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Expected type 'Zu', but it was: a custom Object object
```

I tried running `result[0].update({ userLikes: arrayUnion(publisherId) })` and I get `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: result[0].update is not a function`.

I've also tried

```
const docRef = doc(db, "mixrCocktails", cocktail.id)
await updateDoc(docRef, { userLikes: arrayUnion(publisherId) })
```

And I get

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: n.indexOf is not a function
```

In the docs (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) I see they use a document ref in the following way:

```
import { doc, updateDoc, arrayUnion, arrayRemove } from "firebase/firestore";

const washingtonRef = doc(db, "cities", "DC");

// Atomically add a new region to the "regions" array field.
await updateDoc(washingtonRef, {
    regions: arrayUnion("greater_virginia")
});
```

In the example, I understand "DC" is the ID Firebase sets for the document. But how can I create a ref by querying for another field different than that?

Full code can be found here: https://github.com/coccagerman/mixr

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your second code snippet (`cocktail.id`), where is cocktail defined. Also can you ensure DB is defined and initialised ?

Comment: Cocktail is an object with this structure:

{
    "publisherId": "7hg4IPFhOuOMyAbHUaYJxhtSfv03",
    "name": "Campari & orange",
    "userLikes": [],
    "image": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD//gA",
    "recipeSteps": [
        "Squeeze an orange",
        "Top it with Campari"
    ],
    "description": "Campari & orange",
    "ingredients": [
        "Campari",
        "Orange juice"
    ],
    "id": 1645882651018
}

DB is defined and initialised correctly, as I'm able to execute other queries with no problem from the same screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, if I understand it correctly. You want to query a document using `where` before updating the document result.

You're not referencing the `updateDoc()` properly. Check the snippet that I wrote based on your snippet above. Here's some options:

Using `.map`:

```
const q = query(collection(db, 'mixrCocktails'), where('id', '==', cocktailId));

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
const documents = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }));

for (const document of documents) {
    // console.log(document.id);
    const documentRef = doc(db, 'mixCocktails', document.id);

    if (!isLiked) {
      await updateDoc(documentRef, { userLikes: arrayUnion(publisherId) })
      setIsLiked(true)
    }
    else {
      await updateDoc(documentRef, { userLikes: arrayRemove(publisherId) })
      setIsLiked(false)
    }
}
```

Using `async` method:

```
async function updateDocuments (document) {
    // console.log(document.id);
    const documentRef = doc(db, 'mixrCocktails', document.id);
    
    if (!isLiked) {
      await updateDoc(documentRef, { userLikes: arrayUnion(publisherId) })
      setIsLiked(true)
    }
    else {
      await updateDoc(documentRef, { userLikes: arrayRemove(publisherId) })
      setIsLiked(false)
    }
}

const q = query(collection(db, 'mixrCocktails'), where('id', '==', cocktailId));

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

querySnapshot.forEach((document) => {
    updateDocuments(document);
});
```

You may still improve the written code above for your use-case.

Comment: Thanks man! Massive help.